# How to get all rows from Oracle NoSQL table?

Tags: java, oracle-nosql, nosql

How to get all rows from a Oracle NoSQL table using TableAPI in Java?
I can get records by primary keys values. Example:

```java
    TableAPI tableH = kvstore.getTableAPI();
    Table myTable = tableH.getTable("myTable");
    PrimaryKey key = myTable.createPrimaryKey();
    key.put("item", "Hat");

    List<Row> myRows = null;
    try {
        myRows = tableH.multiGet(key, null, null);
    } catch (ConsistencyException ce) {
    } catch (RequestTimeoutException re) {
    }
    for (Row theRow: myRows) {
        String itemType = theRow.get("item").asString().get();
    }
    System.out.println(itemType);
```

But I can't get primary keys values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify your example, you get all rows by using an empty PrimaryKey for the table and use one of the TableAPI.tableIterator() methods. A note on the example, TableAPI.getTable() will perform a remote call so the Table handle should be stashed and reused.

```
TableAPI tableH = kvstore.getTableAPI();
/* 
 * get the Table, but be careful about doing this frequently,
 * as it performs a remote call.
 */
Table myTable = tableH.getTable("myTable");
PrimaryKey key = myTable.createPrimaryKey();

try {

    /* create and use an iterator on the Row value */
    TableIterator<Row> rowIter = tableH.tableIterator(key, null, null);
    while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIter.next();
        /* do something */
    }

    /* 
     * Or...
     * create and use an iterator on the PrimaryKey values.
     * This is much faster than fetching the data as well if
     * you only need fields in the primary key.
     */
    TableIterator<PrimaryKey> keyIter =
              tableH.tableKeysIterator(key, null, null);
    while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
        PrimaryKey key = rowIter.next();
        /* do something */
    }
} catch (FaultException fe) {
}
```